# Point To A Specific Page Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In Jquery Mobile 2 pages enter the DOM (one which is hidden) when attempting to fire this event

```
$(document).delegate('div[data-role=page]', 'pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
```

It never fires, I am guessing for that reason. Luckily in my case both pages have different ids. How do I change this event to fire on a page with id="AppPage"?

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="AppPage">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to try:

```
$( '#AppPage' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(){
    alert( "Before showing the page AppPage");
});
```

For more information, check the online docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Let me know it this is what you were looking for